Toddler (2 1/2 year old boy) won’t sleep without mum or dad in his bedroom
Wondering if anyone has a solution for a phase we are going through with our 2 1/2 year old son. Since before he was 2, our son has had some real issues with sleeping alone in his room.
He has a pretty typical routine where:

Dinner around 6-6.30pm
Playtime 7.30-7pm
Bath time 7-7.30pm
7.30-8pm PJs on and read a book.
8-8.30pm Milk in cot to fall asleep.

The problem we are facing is that as soon we finish the book, he immediately asks for one of us to sit next to his bed or on the double bed we have in his room as he knows we are about to put him into his cot for bed time. You can actively see the anxiety on his face and hear it in his voice as soon as he knows he has to sleep and that we might leave.
The only way we can get him to sleep now is by lying in the bed in his room till he falls asleep, we then leave to go into our bedroom.
He’ll then wake up at midnight crying out and we’ll have to go in and stroke his head (we normally wait in case he falls back to sleep but he never does) until he falls asleep and then leave to go back to our bedroom.
The next wake up will be 3am and he then cries out even louder and this wake up he needs us to stay in the room with him otherwise he won’t go back to sleep. Both these wake ups are like clockwork and require the same method to get him back to sleep.
We’ve tried all the methods:

I’ll be right back - extending the returns more and more. This resulted in him becoming more worked up each time it got longer and longer.

Cry it out - walk out after saying good night and cuddles etc. we left him for over an hour crying and calling out, jumping in his cot, till we finally went in to comfort him. This was an awful experience for all of us and I don’t know if we could stomach that again.

Edging closer to the door each night. Similar to the "I’ll be right back" approach, he just got more anxious each time we got closer to the door.

Sleeping on the floor/bed and moving that closer to door. Same result as when we sat on the floor moving closer to the door, he would just get more anxious the closer we got.


If anyone has gone through this before, it would be great to hear how you dealt with this. Even to hear that you ended up just staying in their room and the phase passed, I think hearing how long it took would give us some peace knowing there is light at the end of the tunnel and knowing how long that realistically could be.
Thank you community!
Dad
